# How can I use persian numbers with react-number-format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-number-format

I created this component with `react-number-format`

```
const NumberFormatCustom = React.forwardRef(function NumberFormatCustom(
  props,
  ref
) {
  const { onChange, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <NumericFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={ref}
      onValueChange={(values) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: values.value,
          },
        });
      }}
      maxLength={11}
      allowLeadingZeros
      // isNumericString
    />
  );
});
```

and I passed it to my `TextField` component of `MUIv5`.

```
     InputProps={{
            inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
          }}
```

but it doesn't work. the `onChange` prop of my `TextField` don't work at all

I tried some approaches like this :

```
 e.target.value.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, (d) => "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹".indexOf(d))
```

but it didn't work because `onChange` is not working. I tried to add  `replace` function to `value` part of `NumericFormat` but it didn't work either.

how can I handle it?